# Get past static field of jUnit:s @BeforeClass

Tags: java, static, junit, load-order

Is there any way around the classic problem of

```
public class SomeClass implements SomeOtherInterface {

  private static SomeInterface some;

  public SomeClass(SomeInterface someInterface) {
    some = someInterface;
  }

  @BeforeClass
  public static void doSomethingWithInterface() {
    System.out.println(someInterface.someValue()); // prints null
  }
}
```

other than exchanging

```
System.out.println(someInterface.someValue()); // prints null
```

with

```
System.out.println(SomeInterface.someValue());
```

if someValue is static. The problem is that this is for an framework (extension), and and an implementation of SomeInterface is to be provided by the user.

Answer (score 1):

You set the value of the `static` member just in the constructor. So before not having at least one object of that class, you won't be able to access `someValue()`. In Junit the `@Before` annotation might be useful which is executed before each test and is not `static`.

Comment: I guess I can have a Boolean value to indicate if 'someValue()' have been called, and use that from the @Before method.

Comment: You could. However, but what information is the user taking from the `println` anyway (and is it worth your effort to implement it)? If it is testing the compliance to a specific interface contract, it might not be necessary to print anything at all to `System.out`. Especially, since it might not be read. The test cases should clearly document (e.g. in javadoc) what they test and when the developer can expect the tests to fail. If they fail, the according assert messages should be self-explanatory. (Since I don't know your exact use-case, you might have your good reasons though)